# Error printing owner.screenname and owner.url property value (Dailymotion Data API)

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, dailymotion-api

When performing the GET for both the PLAYLIST feature and the VIDEO feature I have had a problem. When performing GET on my console, the request correctly returns the values ​​of the owner.screenname and owner.url attributes, however, when making the same request via AJAX (jQuery) these values, it comes as undefined (Google Chrome console). Could you tell me where I'm going wrong? I'm using the Data API (Dailymotion). I'm making the call from http://localhost:8084 (Apache Tomcat)

Code:

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "GET",  
    url: "https://api.dailymotion.com/video/x26ezj5?fields=id,title,owner,owner.screenname,owner.url",  
    dataType: "json"  
})  
.done(function(data){  
    console.log(data.id);  
    console.log(data.title);  
    console.log(data.owner);   
    console.log(data.owner.screenname);   
    console.log(data.owner.url);   
})  
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){  
    console.log(jqXHR.status + textStatus + errorThrown);  
})  
.always(function(data) {  
    console.log(data);  
});
```

Chrome console:

```
x26ezj5  
Greetings  
x1fz4ii  
undefined  
undefined  
{id: "x26ezj5", title: "Greetings", owner: "x1fz4ii", owner.screenname: "Dailymotion API", owner.url: "https://www.dailymotion.com/DailymotionAPI"}
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it by changing: data.owner.screenname for date ["owner.screenname"] and data.owner.url for data ["owner.url"].